# Name of this "fundamental" theorem in functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

I have the following theorem in my notes, but we didn't see a proof for it. I was wondering if it has a name because the teacher called it "Fundamental Theorem" but I couldn't find anything relevant under that name. $\newcommand{\X}{\mathbb X}$

> **Theorem.** Let $\X$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $T \colon \X \to \X$ be a compact, self-adjoint and positive operator.
>   Then there exist a sequence $\{\mu_k\}$ of positive real eigenvalues of $T$ and a sequence $\{x_k\} \subset \X$ of eigenfuctions ($Tx_k = \mu_k x_k$) such that:
>
> - $\mu_k \searrow 0$ (not necessarily in a strict sense);
> - the eigenfunctions form a basis of $\X$ and Parseval's identity holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably be referred to as the "spectral theorem of (self-adjoint) compact operators", although there is a more general version for normal compact operators (or even normal bounded operators). Note that it is very much like the spectral theorem for self-adjoint (or normal) matrices.

Comment: You don't need to stop there, you can also go to unbounded operators!

Comment: @s.harp Very true.

Comment: Wow. Every time I understand a generalisation I feel like I've made a good step towards a more general comprehension of math, but there are always, two, three, or four more general results that completely cover what I just did!